# how to start sharding in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am trying to learn *sharding* in MongoDb and here is my plan:

[image]

I'm trying to shard the database S001 into 2 different machines.

> **192.xx.xx.60>mongod -configsvr --dbpath S001**
>   ..Now running in port 27019
>
> **192.xx.xx.60>mongo**
>
> > *show dbs*
> >     S001 0.74151GB

Only one database **`S001`** is there

> **192.xx.xx.60>mongos -configdb *192.xx.xx.60:27019,192.xx.xx.61:27019,192.xx.xx.62:27019***
>   ..Some messages...
>
> **192.xx.xx.60>mongos**
>
> > *show dbs*
> >     config 0.54125GB
> >     admin empty

Whereas now it is showing 2 different databases called `config` and `admin`.

I don't understand the following points:
1. how were these 2 new database created?
2. Is my database now sharded?
3. How to continue further?

**FYI:** Still now I haven't set up replication so I'm trying to shard without replication.

Totally stuck and unable to continue further.  Please share your suggestions.

Comment: have you started the mongod daemons on 192.xx.xx.61:27019 and 192.xx.xx.62:27019? These need to be running.

Comment: @user152468 Yes I have started running those mongod daemons.  otherwise `mongos -configdb 192.xx.xx.60:27019,192.xx.xx.61:27019,192.xx.xx.62:27019` would have resulted in error.

Comment: I suggest following the [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) tutorial in the MongoDB manual. It looks like you're at the step where you need to [add shards to the cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/#add-shards-to-the-cluster). You see the `config` and `admin` databases because you've connected your `mongos` to the `config` servers, but you do not have a functional cluster without adding the shards. You'll also need to shard your database and collections once the cluster is setup (as per the tutorial).